# Getting "ERROR 5 Getting File System Type of Destination" Access denied: suing TFS Windows Machine File Copy Task

Tags: tfs, robocopy

I am new to TFS and i am trying to copy artifacts from my TFS server to a windows server using Windows Machine File Copy Task. But i am getting the following error.

"ERROR 5  Getting File System Type of Destination,  Access denied". It is using Robocopy for achieving this.

I can remotely connect to the server and i have admin access. What am i missing here? Please help.

Comment: Are you copying files from the build to the same build server (just another directory) or are you copying from the build server to a different server (through a share for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can remotely connect to the server and i have admin access. What am
>   i missing here?

Azure DevOps/TFS is using **build service account** to run  your build pipeline. The key point here is the build service  just the same as account "I".

If not, you need to give same permission as "I" to that account.

Another way is changing your build service account to "I". This account is configured when you install build agent.

How to change it, you could refer my reply in this question: [azure devops local agent pipeline permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60682283/azure-devops-local-agent-pipeline-permission-denied)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I was able to fix the issue. When i changed my credentials to the owner of the server i could able to deploy. Thanks For the help