# Access Denied problems in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We have created an **Azure Virtual machine scale set agent pool** and started the pipeline in the agent pool. We faced **Access Denied** problems in the jobs due to the tasks not running in the admin mode (CMD, PowerShell, and Final builder) on the VMSS instance. We need to run these tasks in admin mode in the Agent pool.

We couldn’t run an console application too with admin privileges in the VM.

Please provide any suggestions to resolve this issues.

**VMSS Agent Pool:**
[image]

**Pipeline:**
[image]

**Access Denied Issue:**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60682283/azure-devops-local-agent-pipeline-permission-denied

Answer (score 0):

After you setup the scale set agent pool in Azure DevOps, it will use `machinename\azdevops` to run the pipeline task(can validate with 'whoami' in the task as below):

[image]

Remote to the target Scale set VM, the user is "Administrator" by default, the account has administrator permission.

[image]

I can create a file with the account in pipeline.
[image]

> We couldn’t run an console application too with admin privileges in the VM.

If you cannot run the application with admin permission `directly` on VM, suspect it could be blocked the policy which should come from VMSS policy not DevOps.

It's recommended to create a new VMSS, and use it for DevOps agent for a check.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing admin access for selected command:

```
Function Check-RunAsAdministrator()
{
  #Get current user context
  $CurrentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
  
  #Check user is running the script is member of Administrator Group
  if($CurrentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator))
  {
       Write-host "Script is running with Administrator privileges!"
  }
  else
    {
       #Create a new Elevated process to Start PowerShell
       $ElevatedProcess = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";
 
       # Specify the current script path and name as a parameter
       $ElevatedProcess.Arguments = "& '" + $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "'"
 
       #Set the Process to elevated
       $ElevatedProcess.Verb = "runas"

       #Start the new elevated process
       $process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($ElevatedProcess)
       $process.WaitForExit()
       #Exit from the current, unelevated, process
       Exit
    }
}
 
#Check Script is running with Elevated Privileges
$process = Check-RunAsAdministrator

Write-Host "Hi, I am admin"
#Your other commands to open a txt, etc
```

Or try disabling UAC on your VM, maybe it interferes with unintended operations in your tasks when using "AzDevOps" account.

$RegistryUAC="HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"
New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryUAC -Name "EnableLUA" -Value 0 -PropertyType "DWord" -Force